# How to format laptop hard drive to NTFS in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hard-drive, 18.04, windows-10, ntfs

**I have seen question like this but the answers were not what I was looking for.**

On my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop, I want to install windows back, as I got the laptop off of a friend that switched it from windows to Ubuntu. But for some reason when I am installing windows it says that the hard drive has to be formatted to NTFS for windows to be installed. How do I do this?

Edit: This is NOT a duplicate. The answers on other pages are not actually giving correct instruction on what I want to do. When I go into the windows installer by changing boot order in BIOS, I get to "Where should windows be installed?" But when I click on my hard drive it says that windows can be installed because it is not in the NTFS format. What I want to know is how to change my hard drive to this NTFS format so windows can be installed onto it.

Comment: Create a unallocated place from gparted. Then you can convert it to Ntfs. Do you want to dual boot or want to install only windows?

Comment: I want to install windows only and get rid of Ubuntu.

Comment: The Windows installer can partition and format the disk for you, there should be no need to prepare it. If anything, boot from e.g. an Ubuntu live system and delete all partitions. Partition creation and especially formatting should be left for the installer.

Comment: No, when I am installing, it says pick a place to install windows (installing from usb), when I select my hard drive it says "Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. Windows must be installed to a partition formatted as NTFS. Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. The partition is of an unrecognized type."

Comment: This is a WINDOWS question. Installing and formatting to Windows has nothing to do with the current installed operating system. See a windows manual on how to do what you want.

Comment: I want to know how, in Ubuntu, I can reinstall windows and get rid of Ubuntu, this includes changing formatting in an **Ubuntu Environment.** It has to do with the operating system because I am using it to re-format my drive to one windows will use, and I need instructions on how to do so.

Comment: You do not install windows from ubuntu. You install windows from a dvd, usb or from a recovery partition. Formatting is done from the Windows installer. Installing a single OS on a system has nothing to do with the current installed OS. You do not even get to boot or see that OS.

Comment: In the windows installer, it does not allow me to format the primary hard drive. Though for the usb I am using to install it, it does. So in Ubuntu, I need to format the hard drive to NTFS so windows will install on it.